# Как определить, что все элементы первого массива содержатся во втором (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть два массива:

"apple","orange"
и
"apple","banana","orange","watermelon"

Как простейшим образом определить, что все элементы первого массива содержаться во втором?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `for in` и методом `includes`. Еще можно воспользоваться методом `some`.

Comment: А вот для массивов `[1, 1, 2]` и `[1, 2, 3]` какой ожидается ответ? Во втором массиве содержатся обе единицы из первого, или только одна?

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```js
const arr1 = ["apple","orange"];
const arr2 = ["apple","banana","orange","watermelon"];
const isIncluded = (arr1, arr2)=> arr1.every((e) => arr2.includes(e));
console.log(isIncluded(arr1, arr2));
```